# When I want to shutdown Ubuntu appear a pop up notification

Tags: shutdown

When I want to shutdown Ubuntu appear a pop up asking:

> Are you sure you want to close all programs and shut down the computer?

I run the command `top` in the Terminal and aparently there aren't any programs running. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should always be some programs running; if nothing else, there should be top.  There's usually more depending on which desktop environment you're running.

But this pop-up will always appear no matter what might or might not be running.  It also prompts for whether to shut down or restart.  You could create a shortcut that would immediately shut down with no dialog if you wanted, such as a command like `sudo init 0` to shut down, or `sudo shutdown now`.